# Merge property file into application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I have two properties files. Let's say a.properties and b.properties. these file values has been stored in maps created, let say aMap and bMap.

```
@PropertySource(value={ "classpath:a.properties", "classpath:b.properties"})
Class propFile{
   Private Map<String, String> aMap;
   Private Map<String, String> bMap;
}
```

I have to merge these property file into application.properties such that it works same way. Please provide me solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to retrieve your properties by annotating your properties class with [@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) and [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="maps")
public class ConfigProperties {
    private Map<String, String> a;
    private Map<String, String> b;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The corresponding `application.yml` would look as follows:

```
maps:
  a:
    key:
      test1
  b:
    key:
      test2
```

Or alternatively with an `application.properties` file:

```
maps.a.key=test1
maps.b.key=test2
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted also wanted to know if I run this command "mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipNgBuild" where -DskipNgBuild is a invalid flag, but this should still skip test, though it doesn't skip tests. But when I use a command " mvn clean install -DskipTests" it's works Well. Why does it fail to execute valid flag in presence of invalid flag?

Comment: I believe this would be a completely new question. Please post it separately.