# I want to read YAML in the map form. How can I do it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Sample yaml looks like

```
  "mappings":
    "name": "foo"
    "aliases": "abc"
```

Trying to implement it using PropertySourceFactory, but unsuccessful.

```
import import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
//@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:order_config.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class ValidatorConfig {

    @Value("${yaml.mappings}")
    private Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();

    @Value("${yaml.mappings.name}")
    private String create;


    public String getValidatorBean(String tenant, String requestType) {
        System.out.println(mappings);
        return "yes";
    }
}



import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource)
            throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

Have tried using a bunch of methods using @Value, @ConfigurationProperties, but unsuccessful
Can we implement it using YamlMapFactoryBean. Have not been able to find its working demonstration.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml

Comment: Maybe the following will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490852/merge-property-file-into-application-properties/69491001#69491001

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Answer (score 0):

```js
There are 2 ways to do it.
First setup the configmap.yaml file as shown below--
Key1:  
  abc: 'abcval'
  xyz: 'xyzval'
Key2:
  aaa: 'aaaval'
  bbb: 'bbbval'


Add to a config class- 
@Configuration
public class Configfile{
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Map<String,String>> configMap() {
        
        Map<String, Map<String,String>> mapVal=new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/configmap.yaml");       
        mapVal = mapper.mapVal(resource, Map.class);
        return mapVal;
    }
}

1) if you know the key 
    In Service class -
             Use the @Value annotation and get in form of map...
 many google links have it like this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040438/spring-boot-map-a-map-from-application-yaml-to-a-map-with-value-annotation

2) if you dont know the key and want to lookup the prop values based on the key runtime
    In Service class -
        @Resource(name="configMap") 
        private Map<String,Map<String,String>> configMap;
        String keyname = getKeyName()
        Map<String,String> keyFieldsmap= configMap.get(keyname);
```