# Spring Boot: Map a map from application.yaml to a map with @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a yaml file application.yaml in src/main/resources/:

```yaml
it:
  env:
    key1: 'val1'
    key2: 'val2'
```

now I want the values in it.env mapped to a map in java. And I tried the following approaches:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class Test {
   
    @Value("${it.env.key1:'unknown'}")
    private String key1;

    @Value("${it.env}")
    private Map<String, String> envConfig;

    @Value("#{${it.env}}")
    private Map<String, String> envConfig;

}
```

But all I get is an error:
@Value("${it.env}") gives me:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

@Value("#{${it.env}}") gives me:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: How are ${KEY1:val1} and ${KEY2:val2} resolved in your YML file ? Is it only the correct value associated with the key ?

Comment: ${KEY1:val1} will evaluate to 'val1' if there is no environment variable with the name KEY1 set. I removed this as it is not relevant for the question and is only confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you don't use @Value but use @ConfigurationProperties. For that you need add a new class.

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "it")
public class TestEnvProperties {

    Map<String, String> env;

    // Getters and setter...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following yaml format (1) using the @Value parsing structure (2) is the way to go

(1)

```
it:
  env:
    key1: 'value1'
    key2: 'value2'
```

(2)

```
@Value("#{${it.env}}")
private Map<String, String> envConfig;
```

My guess is that the resolution of ${KEY1:val1} **is not** 'value1' and same thing with the resolution of ${KEY2:val2}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the use of placeholders in the application.yaml is a bit distracting in my question I will remove them. ${KEY1:val1} will evaluate to 'val1' if there is no environment variable with the name KEY1 set.